# Use VBA to remove leading and trailing blank spaces but keeping blanks within a string

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to clean and format some set of data obtained from an accounting system and I have been able to create VBA code to use TRIM or CLEAN functions in the specific column ranges.

The thing is that I need to keep the blank spaces within the strings (can be 2, 3 or more blanks) but still remove the leading/trailing spaces and the mentioned functions reduce the inner spaces to 1. This does not work for me as the data is used as a key to match other information in further steps of the process. Bare in mind that leading/trailing blanks can be the result of space bar key, any other character that appears as a blank or even contains line breaks, so again, I want all of these removed but inner blanks. Strings can be made of alphanumeric characters.

I'm using this in a Private Sub (code is execute via a click in a button placed in the worksheet).

```
Dim rng1a As Range
Dim Area1a As Range
Set rng1a = Range("F2:F35001")

  For Each Area1a In rng1a.Areas
    Area1a.NumberFormat = "@"
    Area1a.Value = Evaluate("IF(ROW(" & Area1a.Address & "),CLEAN(TRIM(" & Area1a.Address & ")))")
  Next Area1a
```

Example (in range F2:F35001):

```
Original:  Sample  Text   for Review.     *(there are blanks after the string)
Result:Sample Text for Review.
Desired:Sample  Text   for Review.
```

I made some research for a couple of weeks and haven't been able to find a solution that keeps the inner blanks "as is" and avoid as much as possible duplicate question in the forum. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56718822/edit) to include more information.

Comment: Can you give a better illustration of the data you have, what is happening with the code you're currently using, and what you WANT to happen? Like `   data 01`  should be `data 01` ? If spaces are a problem for illustration, substitute with a more visible character like `!`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with regular expressions:

```
Option Explicit
Function trimWhiteSpace(s As String) As String
    Dim RE As Object

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "^\s*(\S.*\S)\s*"
    trimWhiteSpace = .Replace(s, "$1")
End With
End Function
```

Explanation of the Regex

### Trim leading and trailing white space

```
^\s*(\S.*\S)\s*
```

Options: Case sensitive; ^$ match at line breaks

- [Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) (line feed, line feed, line separator, paragraph separator)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`
- [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\S.*\S)`

  - [Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\S`
  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
  - [Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\S`
- [Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`

$1

- [Insert the text that was last matched by capturing group number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) `$1`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

On the other hand, if you want to avoid regular expressions, and if your only leading/trailing "white-space" characters are `space`, `tab` and `linefeed`, **AND** if the only "internal" white space characters are the `space`, you could use:

```
Function trimWhiteSpace(s As String) As String
    trimWhiteSpace = Trim(Replace(Replace([a1], vbLf, ""), vbTab, ""))
End Function
```

Note that the VBA Trim function (unlike the worksheet function), only removes leading and trailing spaces, and leaves internal spaces unchanged.  But this won't work if you have `tab`'s within the string that need to be preserved.

Either of the above can be incorporated into your macro.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the LTRIM function to remove leading spaces then RTRIM to remove the trailing ones which will leave the internal ones intact?

From your description you don't expect TAB characters or Carriage Returns in the middle of your strings so you could just do a replace for them:

```
strSource = Replace(strSource, vbTab, "")
strSource = Replace(strSource, vbCrLf, " ")
```