# Eliminate blank spaces in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, trim

I have a standard worksheet exported from the system and when there is no information for the cell, the system fills it with blank spaces.
I use a variable to receive the cell value and then check if there's any information.
When there is, I eliminate blank spaces on both sides of the string using Trim, but, when there is no information in the cell, the variable receive a chain of blank spaces, which Trim doesn't work.
Example:
Cell with information - "  1A90 ". Using Trim - "1A90"
Cell without information - "          ". Using Trim - "          ".
I want to convert the result to empty or "".
Anybody can help me?

Comment: Always helps to show your existing code  `? Len(Trim("    "))` returns `0` so maybe those are not just spaces?  Is the export from a web application?  Sometimes you'll get `Chr(160)` (non-breaking space character) from a web export, instead of spaces.

Comment: TpContr = Trim(Cells(var, 11).value) returns "          ".  If I use len, it returns 10.

Comment: Loop over one of the problem cells' values, and debug.print each character and its ASCII code number - that will help you figure out the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry @TimWilliams, It's the first time a make a question and I still don't know how to use tags in the comments.

Comment: You can use backticks to format small code segments, but if you want to add multiple lines then edit your question and it the code there.

Comment: Thanks Tim... I was trying to avoid loop cuz there are a lot of lines and cell to check, but It seems there is no other way... The ASCII value is 160, so it's not just a blank space.

Comment: You need to remove the white spaces and ther might be more white spaces than just chr(160). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56720228/6600940) is a function to do something like that.

Comment: Thanks @Storax, but in my case the spaces are really just chr(160). I've checked in all other worksheets and cells.

Comment: Yes, this time. Next time you get the exported worksheet with other white spaces. But never mind you will have the trouble to clean that file ;-)

Comment: `TpContr = Trim(Replace(Cells(var, 11).value, Chr(160), " "))` (for example) should do it unless there are other "non-space" characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the range you want to clean and run this sub routine.

```
Sub CleanTrimCells_Evaluate()
SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com/the-code-vault

Dim rng As Range
Dim Area As Range

'Weed out any formulas from selection
  If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Set rng = Selection
  Else
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
  End If

'Trim and Clean cell values
  For Each Area In rng.Areas
    Area.Value = Evaluate("IF(ROW(" & Area.Address & "),CLEAN(TRIM(" & Area.Address & ")))")
  Next Area
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this remove characters like Chr(160) as well?. AFAIK CLEAN will not remove them

Comment: The above code will not remove Chr(160) as is, you could put in this line `Cells.Replace Chr(160), ""` in the "Area" loop just before the `Area.Value = Evaluate("IF ...` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the best answer, but it worked.

`Function limpa_espacos(texto As String)
For i = 1 To Len(texto)
    
    If Asc(Mid(texto, i, 1)) = 160 Then
        var_texto = ""
    Else
        var_texto = Mid(texto, i, 1)
    End If
    
     limpo = limpo & var_texto
Next i

limpa_espacos = limpo
End Function`